# How to map a node to the vector it is being represented by after using karateclub's DeepWalk

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm trying to find a way to map the nodes to the vectors that represent them. This is a simple example to help me explain my problem better:

```
from karateclub.node_embedding.neighbourhood.deepwalk import DeepWalk
import networkx as nx

# Creathe the directed graph
graph = nx.DiGraph()

# Populate the graph with nodes and edges
graph.add_node(0)
graph.add_node(1)
graph.add_node(2)
graph.add_node(3)

graph.add_edge(1,3)
graph.add_edge(1,0)
graph.add_edge(0,2)
graph.add_edge(2,3)
graph.add_edge(3,1)

# Create graph embbeding using DeepWalk
deep_walk = DeepWalk()
deep_walk.fit(graph)
vec_graph = deep_walk.get_embedding()
```

Let's say we have this code. Is there some way to know which node of the graph `graph` corresponds to which vector? For example, if we have the node `graph.nodes[0]`, I want to be able to say that it corresponds to the vector `vec_graph[0]`.

One way I found that is supposed to be correct, although I personally don't find it very reliable, is to construct a dictionary in the same execution of the code as the construction of `graph` and `vec_graph`

```
embedding_dict = {int(index): vec_graph[int(index)].tolist() for index in sorted(graph.nodes)}
```

I don't know what to do with this problem.

PS. The nodes of the graph are always added in ascending order of their id. That is, if 3 nodes are added to the graph in the empty graph, it will look like this:

```
graph.add_node(0)
graph.add_node(1)
graph.add_node(2)
```

and if more nodes where to be added it would go from 3 and so on.